# How to set distance between connected vertices in graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'm new at making graphs in mathematica 9, so I don't know if this question is contained in some of already asked ones. I started making it to visualize a polytope, which is build by a sertain algorithm. There are enumerated vertices and we know which points are connected, there are stored in `graphList` list and use the function:

```
GraphPlot3D[graphList, Boxed -> False, VertexLabeling -> False, 
 VertexRenderingFunction -> ({Sphere[#, 0.05], Black} &)]
```

Unfortunatly, when in my case graph gets very complex to visualize (for exapmle several 3D polytopes are put at each other), and it compresses the image. Therefore, I wonder is there a way to order program to make fixed distance between connected vertices, and while changing viewpoint don't change frame?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: `EdgeWeight` command cannot be used in `GraphPlot3D` as it is in these answers.

Comment: @Giorgi It does work with `Graph3D` (not the obsolete `GraphPlot3D`).